# How to target a tag once an input is checked

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the appearance of the content in the `<main>` tag of my HTML page when an input box in the header nav is checked. This problem applies to a project I am working on but here is a simplified version showing the structure of my code:

```css
nav input:checked+main {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  Main page content
</main>
```

Ideally I would like to target the `<footer>` that succeeds the `<main>` tag as well. I have tried various selector combinations but the style of the main content does not change. Please note that ideally I do not want to change the structure of the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You can place that checkbox outside of `<header>` and use a pseudo-checkbox made of `<label>` in its place. This has wide browser support and is JS-free.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I am doing! My code snippet was just the simplest way to demonstrate my issue. Appreciative of the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `nav input:checked+main` because main isn't a sibling of the input (which is what the adjacent sibling combinator `+` checks for). You can try the newish [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class instead:

```css
header:has(nav input:checked) + main {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  Main page content
</main>
```

The way this works is basically targeting `header + main` only if the condition is the `:has(nav input:checked)` part is true.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer.
for older browser support you need to move your input element outside the `header` element and then you can write below css for make this possible.
Browser support for `has` [here](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked~main  {
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
    <main>
        Main page content
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra information. I found out `:has` support for Firefox should be coming [soon](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/discussions/when-is-has-css-selector-going-to-be-fully-implemented-in/m-p/27010/highlight/true#M10711).